# Where does "current state" is stored in event sourcing?

Tags: events, event-handling, cqrs, event-sourcing, eda

I understand cqrs, but I'm having problems with a part of event sourcing. Everyone says "You don't store the aggregate's current state, you store the sequence of events that were applied to that aggregate". Fine by me. But in order to apply a command and produce an event, you need the current aggregate state. Take this table for an example (it is a sequence of API calls). Let's say I have this business rule: "A post can be updated at most twice".
[requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2qxm.png)

In this example, the third attempt to edit a post should fail, and no event should be produced and stored. Assume we are not using the approach "fetch all events from the event store, build the aggregate, apply the command, produce the event, store the event". In that case, where is the current aggregate's state stored?
If it is stored somewhere, isn't this against "you don't store the aggregate.."?

I have been through several articles and talks and examples on the internet. But I always come to the same conclusion/answer. I've seen people taking advantage of the projections in order to check domain invariants/business rules, but projections are eventually consistent and could lead to race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand cqrs, but I'm having problems with a part of event sourcing.

Not your fault; the literature sucks.

---

> I've seen people taking advantage of the projections in order to check domain invariants/business rules, but projections are eventually consistent and could lead to race conditions.

You don't get race conditions because people are using a (logical) lock to prevent write collisions on the history.  Stripping away distracting details, the happy path would look something like:

```
acquire lock
read previous events
compute new events
write new events
release lock
```

In practice, it's common to instead use conditional writes, using stream metadata to ensure that nothing changed while the domain logic was running

```
read previous events
compute new events
acquire lock
write-if new events
release lock
```

Think "compare and swap".

Usually this is done via general purpose metadata; we only perform the write if the current version of the history matches the "expected version" of the history (ex the history still has the same number of events in it that we started with).

Comment: is there a framework o lib that i can look into? i don't care about the language

Comment: The API of EventStoreDB might help.  You could also look at MessageDB and the Eventide project.

Comment: ok with the locking thing. but one last question: if you are using projections, doesn't that count as storing current aggregate's state?

Comment: sure, it would be a denormalized view. but still. is like having aggregate's state scattered across several tables.

Comment: I wouldn't call projections current aggregate state - projections are more similar to unlocked cached copies of information (and metadata), usually in a representation more suitable for query than an event history.

Comment: i agree with you. but if you are using that cached copies of information in order to decide the outcome of a command (to produce an event or not), should'nt that be considered aggregate's state?

Comment: I don't think so, but that probably depends on what inferences you draw from "part of the state" vs "not part of the state"

Comment: "Not your fault; the literature sucks."

This is changing.

I have one book completed (beginners book) and another (patterns book) is likely to be first drafted in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

> Assume we are not using the approach "fetch all events from the event store, build the aggregate, apply the command, produce the event, store the event". In that case, where is the current aggregate's state stored? If it is stored somewhere, isn't this against "you don't store the aggregate.."?

Well, if you're not going to use the approach of fetching events to rebuild the aggregate, and you also don't want to maintain and store the current state.. You're simply restricting yourself to pretty much an impossible situation.

Why wouldn't you want to rebuild the aggregate from it's events? That's a very fundamental part of event sourcing.
Storing current state, while not strictly necessary, is also quite fundamental to event sourcing. But as you rightly said, you want to be careful to use projections (stored current state) when applying commands to the aggregate, as they are often "only" eventually consistent and thus might not be suitable for use when certain business rules/invariants need to be ensured.